# Foundation 6 slider update on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, zurb-foundation

I have a Foundation 6 Slider on an html page I use to setup a device parameters. 
On page load, I read the parameters from an xml file and I set the page accordingly.

Regarding the slider, I modify the input number which is connected via `aria-contro`l to the slider. The problem is that the slider does not update. How can I update the slider?

There the html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">
    <label>Audio&nbsp;Volume</label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
    <div class="slider" id="slidervol" data-slider data-end="100" display_selector: "#slidervol">
      <span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderVolOutput"></span>
      <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">
    <input name="AudioVolTxtbox" type="number" style="width: 4em;" tabindex="2" id="sliderVolOutput">
  </div>
</div>
```

and here the javascript I use to update the form on load:

```
function writeDeviceConfForm(xmldoc) {
  var vartxt;
  var element;

  vartxt = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("AudioVolume")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
  document.DeviceConfig.AudioVolTxtbox.value = vartxt; //input box is correctly updated 

  ...
  $('#slidervol').val(33); //this does not work (do nothing)
  $('#slidervol').foundation('slider', 'set_value', 33); //this does not work (error: slider is not an accepted parameter)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `display_selector` isn't a valid `attribute` as far as a `slider` is concerned, so you can get rid of it. I'm assuming you're calling `$(document).foundation()` to initialize the slider?, if not, make sure you do so at the bottom of the `body`.

In order to update the `slider`'s value, use `Foundation.Slider.defaults.intialStart`. The `Foundation` object contains properties representing all of the available plugins. Each plugin has a `defaults` object that consists of numerous properties you can override before initialization.

These two lines will achieve what you want:

```
Foundation.Slider.defaults.initialStart = 33;
$(document).foundation();
```

It's important that `$(document).foundation()` is called after setting any defaults as otherwise the changes will not take effect. `$(document).foundation()` will target all of the Foundation plugins on the page, which is what you want on the initial page load.

If later on you want to specifically target the `slider`, you can do the following:

```
var target = document.getElementById("slidervol");    
var options = {
  "initialStart": 33
};

var elem = new Foundation.Slider($(target), options);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/5r1cw0qa/)**

Comment: The second part of your answer solves my problem. I also removed the display_selector. The foundation was already correctly initialized with $(document).foundation(); I spent some time in trying to fix my problem: is there some documentation available on the topics which involves the solution you provided? Thank you Yass.

Comment: No probs. The documentation is lacking when it comes to initializing plugins and I discovered the above through trial and error. The process is the same for other plugins, with the only difference being in the options.